# How ignore testing coverage tsx files in Jest

Tags: typescript, unit-testing, jestjs, test-coverage

I use Jest for testing in my project. When I start test coverage Jest see all files include jsx files, but I want to ignore tsx files in coverage. How can I ignore them using my config in package json?
I have this configuration in package.json for Jest

```
  "jestConfig": {
    "coveragePathIgnorePatterns": "['src/**/*.tsx']",
    "jest": {
      "verbose": true
    }
  },
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this to ignore patterns

```
"^.+\\.tsx$"
```

Hope this works for you.